# AngularJS get the values in a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a table name Post, the function below Posts.query give me all the post and stock them in a variable postsATraiter.

```
Posts.query({}, function() {
    $scope.postsATraiter = $scope.posts;
});
```

This works fine I can do a :

```
console.log($scope.postsATraiter.length);
```

This give me the number of post who are in my table, but now I would like to display the value inside my postsATraiter ( date for exemple ).

I try this :

```
console.log(postsATraiter.valueOf(1).date);
```

This is not working, I think valueOf is not the correct function for get one element, but I don't know which one I need to use. Thanks for answer

Comment: Is `postsATraiter` an array??

Comment: If so just access the array with `[1]` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the array of objects and print the needed property value as

```
$scope.postsATraiter.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.date);
});
```

The function is called for each object in the array.

To access the first element's `date` property you can simply do

```
$scope.postsATraiter[0].date
```